# Reactive Framework Trouble with MultiCast and Subscribing to Subject

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've just started learning how to use the Reactive Framework and am struggling with being able to multicast publish to more than one subscriber.

I had everything working fine like this:

```
m_MessagePublisher = m_ServerClient.MessageQueue
      .GetConsumingEnumerable()
      .ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default);

var genericServerMessageSubscriber = m_MessagePublisher
      .Where(message => message is GenericServerMessage)
      .Subscribe(message =>
      {
          // do something here
      }
```

But then I realized that this didn't support multicast and when I tried to attach another subscriber that should have been hit by the same message it won't fire. I have been reading into the .MultiCast extension and trying to figure out how Subject plays into this but haven't been able to get it to work yet:

```
var subject = new Subject<BesiegedMessage>();

var messagePublisher = m_ServerClient.MessageQueue
      .GetConsumingEnumerable()
      .ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
      .Multicast(subject);

// All generic server messages are handled here
var genericServerMessageSubscriber = subject
      .Where(message => message is GenericServerMessage)
      .Subscribe(message =>
      {
            // do something here
      }
```

But now none of the subscribers are being hit including the single one that was working fine before. What am I missing here in order to be able to properly multicast to more than one subscriber?

UPDATE: Using Subscribe(subject) instead of Multicast(subject) seems to be working to multicast which leaves me very confused as to what .MultiCast() is for

Comment: Ever have an answer waiting for a question? Was just explaining multicast the other day to a colleague, hence my rapidly typed in (and non sequitur) initial response, but I've edited since. :)

Comment: It definitely takes an "inverted" way of thinking - notably, declaring the shape of your data over time, tinkering with it along the way like a potter with clay. Have fun :)

Comment: I think you could swap Where(msg=>msg is GenericServerMessage) for OfType<GenericServerMessage>() or Cast<GenericServerMessage>() if your source is IObservable<object>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Haha - serves me right for reading too fast - what you are asking is WAY simpler...that said, I think the below is important, so I'm leaving it...So, your problem - try adding this line:

```
var messagePublisher = m_ServerClient.MessageQueue
  .GetConsumingEnumerable()
  .ToObservable(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
  .Multicast(subject)
  // Here: connectable observables are a PITA...
  .RefCount();
```

END EDIT:

Hmm...how to describe `Multicast`...I guess let's go by example:

Say you've got something like this - what do you think it produces?

```
int delay = 100;
var source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay));
var publishingFrontend = new Subject<string>();

// Here's "raw"
var rawStream = source;
using(rawStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", x)))
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    using(rawStream.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Inner: {0}", x)))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 5);
}
```

Since you are subscribing to the stream raw, new subscribers basically start from scratch:

(this won't 100% match if you re-run, since I took the wussy way out by `Thread.Sleep`, but should be close)

```
0
1
2
Inner: 0
3
Inner: 1
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Hmm...so if we want to "tie in mid-stream", we use the `Publish().RefCount()` pattern:

```
var singleSource = source.Publish().RefCount();
using(singleSource.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", x)))
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    using(singleSource.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Inner: {0}", x)))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 5);
}
```

Which produces something like:

```
0
1
2
Inner: 2
3
Inner: 3
4
Inner: 4
5
6
7
8
9
```

So let's say we didn't have the `Publish()` operator - how could we *simulate* it?

```
Console.WriteLine("Simulated Publish:");
// use a subject to proxy values...
var innerSubject = new Subject<long>();
// wire up the source to "write to" the subject
var innerSub = source.Subscribe(innerSubject);
var simulatedSingleSource = Observable.Create<long>(obs =>
{
    // return subscriptions to the "proxied" subject
    var publishPoint = innerSubject.Subscribe(obs);        
    return publishPoint;
});
```

Running this, we get:

```
Simulated Publish:
0
1
2
Inner: 2
3
Inner: 3
4
Inner: 4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Woot!

*but there is another way...*

```
Console.WriteLine("MulticastPublish:");
var multicastPublish = source.Multicast(new Subject<long>()).RefCount();    
using(multicastPublish.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}", x)))
{
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    using(multicastPublish.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Inner: {0}", x)))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(delay * 3);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(delay * 5);
}
```

Output:

```
MulticastPublish:
0
1
2
Inner: 2
3
Inner: 3
4
Inner: 4
5
6
7
8
9
```

EDIT:

In fact, all of the `ConnectableObservable` generating extensions rely on a `Multicast`/`Subject` pairing:

```
Publish() => Multicast(new Subject<T>)
Replay() => Multicast(new ReplaySubject<T>)
PublishLast() => Multicast(new AsyncSubject<T>)
```

Comment: Isn't he really after `.Publish().RefCount()` instead of `Multicast` so he doesn't have to manufacture his own Subject that he has no specific use for?

Comment: @Brandon `Publish` actually uses `Multicast` under the hood anyways - basically it's the same code, just one is shorthand for the other.

Comment: Also if he used the subject, no need to have the variable, just new it up in the Mulitcast operator...which then takes you back to just use Publish. Multicast is really for when you want to use one of the other subjects.

Comment: @leecampbell true! Altho if memory serves, each of the Multicast/Subject pairings has an equivalent: async, etc - I'd have to check my notes for the exact mapping.

Comment: @LeeCampbell Aha, found mah notes! Have added in a blurb at the end of the answer showing the pairings.

Comment: Yep, that is all that is happening. As documented http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#Multicast